# Android GeoFencing

Tags: android, geofencing

I am developing an Android application for location based alerts. I have my several employees working in different parts of city. I want to know when they enter or exit a specific place.
I know about Geo-fencing API and I implemented it to set alerts for my own location. Now I am looking a way to use Geo-fencing to monitor my clients location. Is it possible with Geo-fencing API to monitor other persons location for alerts? Please guide me in this regard thanks.